# How to add custom view to JSQMessagesViewController cell so that it includes one view with some buttons and text view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1820 this library for chat application.  By using this libary I am able to send images and video, but my app needs to send one view with some button and text. Like when user sends some text it will appear to others as text and button and then when somebody clicks the button one push notification will be generated. I am not able to figure it out how can I achieve this.

[image]

Here is screen shot how I want my custom view to be. It has some text user has typed and has 2 button for accept and reject.

Comment: can you show a screenshot of how you want your custom view to look ?

Comment: @Shubhank added screenshot

Comment: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/blob/develop/Documentation/faq.md#2-providing-your-own-cell-prototypes this has info on providing custom cell types it seems

Comment: @Shubhank thax for this link. can u plz help me out with its point 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you create your own custom view for this. You can use the `JSQIncomingCollectionViewCell.xib` or `JSQOutgoingCollectionViewCell.xib` as a template for your self.

1. Copy them from the example project and paste them into your own
2. Rename the files to something else like `CellWithConfimationButtons`
3. In your ChatViewController i.e. what ever you called the view that is a subclass of 'JSQMessagesViewController'. Add these two lines

   self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CellWithConfimationButtons", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "incomingCell")
       self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CellWithConfimationButtons", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "outgoingCell")
4. Now you can add your buttons to the xib files [image: Xib With Buttons]
5. Add Constraints so that it lays its self out right.
6. Set your Images for those and then you need to make your files that support this guy. Just like `JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellOutgoing.m` and `JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellOutgoing.h` Then you need to add you `IBOutlets` for the buttons and add the actions and logic in that file

Then you need to set a flag or some way of determining that the message is this type of message with buttons.

7. Then in your `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

you check for that flag and get your cell

`if message.flag == true let cell = collectionView.dequeableCellWithIdentifier("incomingCell")`

Then set everything up.

I hope that helps. let me know if I can help more.

Comment: I am following this procedure, and it is helpfule, But There is one major issue , All Previous Cell get Replaces when I scroll

Comment: I followed the steps and the Incoming Bubble just disappears. any idea?

Comment: You would need to add your code for me to be able to make any assessment.