# JSQMessagesViewController Custom Cell Auto layout Issue - IOS

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using JSQMessagesViewController and I created a custom cell according to this answer.
[How to add custom view to JSQMessagesViewController cell so that it includes one view with some buttons and text view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373082/how-to-add-custom-view-to-jsqmessagesviewcontroller-cell-so-that-it-includes-one)

Now I am struggling to set auto layout constrains correctly. So, the message bubble not display correctly. Please help me set the constraints correctly

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey I answered that question. Let me see if I can help. Would you mind sharing what you have so far in the way of constraints or even sharing your code I could take a look and send you in the right direction

Comment: @DanielLeonard Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I have set contains as you said. But still I have issue in setting constraints for the textview and bubble container view. I can share my code with you. How can I share it? Also, see the screen shot after i set the contains as you said

Comment: GitHub is the easiest.

Comment: @DanielLeonard Github repo: https://github.com/smartsanja/JSQMessageController_CustomCell

Comment: Please see JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming.xib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So lets take a stab at this. So first things that I would do it set a constraint for the first button to be equal hight of the other. You can accomplish a couple of ways but I will only describe one here for brevity. You can do hold the `control` button on your computer and select `button1` and drag to `button2`. This will present you with a couple of options that look like this.
[image: Options for Constraints]

You want to select `Equal Heights` this will make it so both your buttons have the same hight. Then you will want to give it a hight. Once again hold down the `control` button on your keyboard but this time click `button1`  drag and release within `button1`. you should get something along the lines of this.

[image: Constraints for a single item]

If you do not get the desired options try dragging in a diagonal direction. Xcode is tying to guess what constraints you want based on the direction of your drag. I.E. If you drag vertically you should get the `Height` option.

Then you can go to the properties inspector on the right and set a number for how high you would like. Text is normally around 12pt so I would go with about 30pt or more for the hight of a button. Then add a constraint for spacing between them and leading and trailing to the containing view or you could give them a standard width and center them in the view. Which ever fits best for you.

Edit:

You should also adjust the bubble size calculation. 
It can be found in the JSQMessagesBubblesSizeCalculator class.
Eg: In the

```
 - (CGSize)messageBubbleSizeForMessageData {
 if([messageData isOptionMessage]){ 
  // add button height also (In this case i have set constant 200. But we have to calculate the actual button heights instead) 
     finalSize = CGSizeMake(finalWidth, stringSize.height + verticalInsets + 200)
  } else { 
       finalSize = CGSizeMake(finalWidth, stringSize.height + verticalInsets)
  }
}
```

Let me know if you need any more help and keep up the good work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I solved my issue. It was not with auto layout. I can modify the message bubble height in this class JSQMessagesBubblesSizeCalculator.

Comment: Awesome I am glad you figured it out I would love to add it to the answer would you mind sharing the code that fixed it and I will add it to the answer. But great work.

Comment: After set the constraints in the xib, you need to adjust the bubble height according to the contents eg: buttons. In the JSQMessagesBubblesSizeCalculator class there's method which calculate the bubble height based on the textView height. We need add the button heights to the calculation too.

Comment: Eg: In the - (CGSize)messageBubbleSizeForMessageData method, we can set something like this. if([messageData isOptionMessage]){
            // add button height also (In this case i have set constant 200. But we have to calculate the actual button heights instead)
            finalSize = CGSizeMake(finalWidth, stringSize.height + verticalInsets + 200);
        }
        else{
            finalSize = CGSizeMake(finalWidth, stringSize.height + verticalInsets);
        }